# JWPlayer Mute pre-roll Ads

Tags: javascript, html, flash, jwplayer, jwplayer6

i am a newbie with this, so i'll try to explain what is my problem.

Currently i have a jwplayer that runs pre-rolls ads on a test web page and i need to mute the ads sounds. The problem is that some ads overlaps the player and no matter what i do simply don't mute the ad. In the page the player is displayed on an html object (below the code) with an .swf as data, this flash is created by jwplayer and i can't make changes of it.

I've tried with the jwplayer API set volume to 0 and set mute true and stuff like that and nothing. On the page a got this code:

```js
jwplayer().onReady(function(event){
    jwplayer().setMute(true);
});
```

also i've tried

```js
jwplayer().onAdPlay(function(event)
       jwplayer().setVolume(0);  });
```

And this is the html object

```html
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://assets-jpcust.jwpsrv.com/player/6/6124956/jwplayer.flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div" name="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div" class="jwswf swfPrev-beforeswfanchor0 swfNext-afterswfanchor0" tabindex="0">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</object>
```

and as i said before its set the player volume to mute but not the ad. So if someone know how to do this let me know.

P.S: English is not my native language

Comment: Do you have a link? Please note, if the ad is VPAID, we might not have access to the volume.

Comment: Sorry for answer late. Try this link www.lationgroup.com/test/test_player_optimatic.html and you are right, the ad is VPAID. But it can be muted with a different approach, i don't know how but it can be done. The ads are dislayed on top of the player and maybe i can do the same, put a div or another element of top of the ads or embed it somehow

Comment: lationgroup.com does not exist. Also since it is VPAID, we don't have control over that ad's volume.

Comment: Sorry it's latinongroup.com, my mistake. I already know that i am looking for a different workaround. If you or someone else  have any idea similar to what I said before please help me. Thanks anyway for answer so quickly

Comment: Yeah, you need to use VAST then.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, but unfortunately I can't. I'm still working on this

Comment: You need to make sure that your ad network's creatives are properly formed so they can react to volume events dispatched from our player. We have no control over their creatives (.swf files).